# Windows mutex object and semaphore

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

Can a Windows mutex object be replaced by a binary semaphore or does the windows mutex object have some specific features that I missed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mutex, in the context of winapi, is a kernel object that supports synchronization across not just multiple threads, but multiple processes, as well as supporting access control.

While it's still technically a binary semaphore, it's much heavier than a single atomic `locked` flag.

If you're looking for a lightweight mutex for synchronizing threads within a single process, look at the [Critical Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.